# React - Mapped array not passing props correctly to child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am making a dashboard component which displays rendered previews and code for HTML snippets. Inside of the dashboard component I am mapping the array of snippets using `.map`. Each mapped snippet is going to have a delete function (already built) and an update function.

For the update function to work each snippet has it's own child modal component. I need to pass the ID of the snippet to the modal component where I can combine the ID with the new content before updating the database and state.

However, I'm making a mistake somewhere as I pass the ID as props to the modal.

`.map` used inside of my Dashboard.js Dashboard class component.

```
{this.state.snippets.map(snippet => (
  <>
    <div key={snippet._id} className="holder--pod">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content__snippet-preview">
          Snippet preview
        </div>
        <div className="content__body">
          <h4>{snippet.name}</h4>
          <p>{snippet.details}</p>
          <p>{snippet._id}</p> //THIS WORKS
          <pre>
            <code>{snippet.content}</code>
          </pre>
        </div>
        <div className="content__button">
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete(snippet._id)}>
            Delete
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Open
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Modal
      sid={snippet._id} //PASS ID HERE
      show={this.state.show}
      handleClose={this.hideModal}
    ></Modal>
  </>
))}
```

### This renders the snippets below (3 snippet pods, with their database ID included).

[image]

The open button opens the modal (Modal.js) below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import api from '../api'

export default class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      details: '',
      content: '',
      message: null,
    }
  }
  handleInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    })
  }
  handleClick = id => event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(id)
  }

  render() {
    const { sid, show, handleClose } = this.props
    console.log(sid)
    const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-flex' : 'modal display-none'
    return (
      <div id="Modal" className={showHideClassName}>
        <div id="modal-main">
          <h4>Edit snippet {sid}</h4>
          <form>
            Name:{' '}
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.name}
              name="name"
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />{' '}
            <br />
            Details:{' '}
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.details}
              name="details"
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />{' '}
            <br />
            Content:{' '}
            <textarea
              value={this.state.content}
              name="content"
              cols="30"
              rows="10"
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />{' '}
            <br />
            <button onClick={this.handleClick(sid)}>TEST ME</button>
          </form>
          <button onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
          {this.state.message && (
            <div className="info">{this.state.message}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `console.log` just under the render actually pastes the correct 3 ID's the console.
[image]


However, calling the ID (`sid`) within the Modal.js return will only show the last snippet ID, no matter which Modal I open. The same goes for pushing that ID to the handleClick function where I intend to combine the ID with an update package.

Comment: this.showModal probably sets this.show to true so it results in all modal showing, you can only see the last one (top one) but if you have pressed F12 and inspect the elements or use react dev tool, you can see they all have show property to true.

Comment: @HMR you hit the nail on the head. Can't beleive I didn't see that.

Comment: As others posted; the handleDelete is suspect too unless it's a curried function `handleDelete = (id)=>()=>....`

Comment: @HMR paste your comment as the answer so I can give you brownie points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below as initiated by HMR in the comments.

The problem was all the modals were showing and just the last one was visible. 
Fixed by moving the modal out of the `.map` and instead updating the ID from within the `.map` to the state and passing the state ID to a new nested component within the modal.

Also switched to using dynamic CSS to show and hide the modal based on the state.

### Dashboard.jsx

```
export default class Snippets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showModal = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      snippets: [],
      show: false,
      sid: '',
    }
  }

  handleDelete = id => event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    api
      .deleteSnippet(id)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('DATA DELETED')
        api.getSnippets().then(result => {
          this.setState({ snippets: result })
          console.log('CLIENT UPDATED')
        })
      })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ message: err.toString() }))
  }
  handleModal = id => {
    this.setState({ sid: id })
    this.showModal.current.showModal()
  }
  //<div id="preview">{ReactHtmlParser(snippet.content)}</div>

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Modal ref={this.showModal} handleClose={this.hideModal}>
          <ModalUpdate sid={this.state.sid} />
        </Modal>
        <div className="Dashboard">
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="holder">
                <div className="content">
                  <div className="content__body">
                    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="break"></div>
              {this.state.snippets.map(snippet => (
                <div key={snippet._id} className="holder--pod">
                  <div className="content">
                    <div className="content__snippet-preview">
                      Snippet preview
                    </div>
                    <div className="content__body">
                      <h4>{snippet.name}</h4>
                      <p>{snippet.details}</p>
                      <p>{snippet._id}</p>
                      <pre>
                        <code>{snippet.content}</code>
                      </pre>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content__button">
                      <button onClick={this.handleDelete(snippet._id)}>
                        Delete
                      </button>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => this.handleModal(snippet._id)}
                      >
                        Open
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
```

### Modal.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    }
  }
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true })
  }
  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="Modal"
        style={{ display: this.state.show === true ? 'flex' : 'none' }}
      >
        <div id="modal-main">
          <h4>Edit snippet </h4>
          {this.props.children}
          <button onClick={() => this.hideModal()}>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

### ModalUpdate.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ModalUpdate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      details: '',
      content: '',
      message: null,
    }
  }
  // handleInputChange = event => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  //   })
  // }
  // handleClick = id => event => {
  //   event.preventDefault()
  //   console.log(id)
  // }

  render() {
    return <h4>ID = {this.props.sid}</h4>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the handleDelete function,. but replacing the line should solve the issue probably

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(snippet._id)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue is the `this.handleDelete(snippet._id)` will fire immediately rather than `onClick`, so you will need to add an anonymous function in the event listener:

```
() => this.handleDelete(snippet._id)
```

instead of

```
this.handleDelete(snippet._id)
```